# Prevent sprite rotation from changing gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have a function in SpriteKit that spawns a sprite (which is a square) at the top of the screen, and then gravity pulls the sprite to the bottom of the screen. I'm trying to get the sprite to rotate smoothly for an indefinite amount of time until it is removed when it reaches the bottom of the screen. The following code is in the class for the sprite:

```
func rotate() {
    var action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: NSTimeInterval(1.5))
    var repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action)
    self.runAction(repeatAction)
}
```

The problem that I am having is that, as the sprite turns, the sprite travels in the direction of the bottom of itself, not towards the bottom of the screen (the direction gravity is supposed to be). To further clarify, the object rotates, but as it rotates to 90 degrees, it travels sideways instead of downwards. This doesn't make sense to me. This is the code I'm using to add gravity in the `didMoveToView()` function:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -1.8)
```

and this is the code used to spawn the sprite (the `rs.rotate()` calls the rotate method that is listed above):

```
func spawnRedSquares() {
    if !self.gameOver {
        let rs = RedSquare()
        var rsSpawnRange = randomNumberBetween(self.leftSideBar.position.x + rs.sprite.size.width / 2, secondNum: self.rightSideBar.position.x - rs.sprite.size.width / 2)
        rs.position = CGPointMake(rsSpawnRange, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + rs.sprite.size.height * 2)
        rs.zPosition = 3
        self.addChild(rs)
        self.rsArray.append(rs)
        rs.rotate()

        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock(self.spawnRedSquares)
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(timeBetweenRedSquares))
        let spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawn])
        self.runAction(spawnThenDelay)
    }
}
```

How can I get the object to rotate, but still fall down as if it were affected by normal gravity?

Comment: How are you adding gravity to your sprite? Please post that relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the rotation action to 'self' which I would assume is your scene as opposed to your sprite. This is causing the entire scene to rotate, and therefore its gravity is rotating as well.

Add the rotating action to your sprite and that should solve the issue.

**Example**: assuming your square sprite is called `squareSprite`:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: NSTimeInterval(2))
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action)
squareSprite.runAction(repeatAction) //Add the repeatAction to your square sprite
```

Comment: I think I was already doing this. I updated the question again to include all of the code that I am currently using. It seems to be just what you suggested here. Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Ah yes, I see that you mentioned the rotate function is inside of your custom sprite class?

Comment: Yes, the rotate function is inside of my custom sprite class, but it's called using `rs.rotate()` which is inside of the SKView.

Comment: Can you try it with just one red square, without the "spawn and delay" action? What does the self.spawnRedSquares do?

Comment: The problem persists, but only 1 block is spawned instead of spawning every few seconds. The issue is that the gravity is changing by 90 degrees when the sprite rotates. That's not what I want though. I want the sprite to rotate 360 infinitely while it's falling.

Comment: Right, but it is strange that gravity would rotate along with your sprite. If you do not call your sprites rotation at all method does the gravity still rotate?

Comment: If I leave the rotation out, the gravity stays the same and the block falls directly down with no rotation.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Your answer is correct, I just needed to use `RedSquare.sprite.runaction(repeatAction)`. This is because I declared the class as an SKNode and defined the SKSpriteNode as an image inside of the class, like so: `self.sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RS\(randIndex)")`. I had to specify that I was rotating the SKSpriteNode and not the SKNode. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome, figured somewhere along the line the wrong thing was being rotated, glad you figured it out.